# MS Access, How can I detect new insert vs update inside trigger macros?

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-data-macro

MS Office 265 ProPlus, Access 2007 - 2016

While defining a "Before Update" macro(?) on a table, I'd like to be able to detect when this is an update to an existing record vs inserting a new record.

I know about and have used the "Old" context tag/prefix in other cases.  In this case I guess "Old" wouldn't exist or be undefined if this is an insert.  Is there a way to detect that?  Is there some other way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Are you referring to Before Change table event?

[image]

> Use the **IsInsert** property to determine whether the Before Change event was triggered by a new record being created or a change to an existing record